# Taking off the last comma from INSERT into WHILE loop

Tags: php

I really need to escape the last comma to prevent SQL errors with the INSERT

Should I use a simple implode, maybe a trim? But how? I don't want to echo those values, just insert them into my database escaping the last comma

```
    if ($handle = fopen($arquivo['tmp_name'], "r")) {

        $pdo = $this->connector->getConnection();

        $firstLine   = true;

        $string = "INSERT INTO vestibular (rg, nome, curso, resultado, colocacaogeral, colocacaocurso, unidade) VALUES ";

        while ($row = fgetcsv($handle , 0 , ";")) {

            if ($firstLine) {
                $firstLine = false;
                continue;
            }

            $string .= "(
                '" . mb_convert_encoding($row[0], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') . "',
                '" . mb_convert_encoding($row[1], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') . "',
                '" . mb_convert_encoding($row[2], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') . "',
                '" . mb_convert_encoding($row[3], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') . "',
                '" . mb_convert_encoding($row[4], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') . "',
                '" . mb_convert_encoding($row[5], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') . "',
                '" . $_POST['unidadeVestibular'] . "'
                ),";

        }

        $statement = $pdo->prepare($string);
        $statement->execute();

        return $statement;

        fclose($handle);

    }


}
```

Could someone help me please? =D

EDIT 1 :

TO CLARIFY: I need to prevent a comma into `$_POST['unidadeVestibular']` to keep the loop going and Insert as it should do

Comment: Honestly, the "easiest" way to do this would be to add each of your rows to an array and then implode the array. (for a given value of easy.)

Comment: You could also look at something like `$string = substr($string,0,strlen($string) - 1);`

Comment: Use Prepared, Parameterized Queries. Your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injection and absolutely wrong. If you insert the values directly into the query, then you're rendering the whole preparing process worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to remove the last character of a string is to use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). The following will extract part of `$string` (everything except the last character) and reassign to `$string`.

`$string = substr($string, 0, -1);`

Answer (score 2):

Use rtrim() function to Strip any characters from the end of a string

```
rtrim($string, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solution

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare(rtrim($string, ","));

$statement->execute();
```